# ffmpeg — how to extract all frames from video, then rebuild video precisely from extracted frames?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm doing a project where I need to alter some frames of a video file. I'm working with a terminal commands right now, but they will eventually turn into a bash or a Python script.

To extract frames, I'm using ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i "file.mp4" "frames/out-%03d.bmp"`

This works and does what I need.

But then, after I altered some of the BMPs, I need to rebuild the file with them. I'm trying to do that with command:

`ffmpeg -i frames/out-%03d.bmp result.mp4`

But I'm facing a problem here: I need to build a video file using the same properties as original file. So I'd keep the framerate, color space, audio stream and other metadata. What would be the right, automated way to do that? I've thought about using

`ffprobe file.mp4`

But I'm not sure how to properly feed this data into a command that builds new video.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've found out that command
`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate file.mp4`
gets you an fps parameter, but when I encoded new video with it, it ran at a bit different speed than original.
The result was 30000/1001, but original video runs at 29.969720 fps, resulting video runs at 29.970030 fps.

Comment: Show your latest `ffmpeg` command where you set the frame rate.

Comment: @llogan it's `ffmpeg -framerate 30000/1001 -i frames/out-%03d.bmp result.mp4`. 30000/1001 is fed as a bash variable.

Comment: Is the original input VFR? https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vfrdet

Comment: @llogan I've checked and it surprisingly was VFR. 
I want my program to be able to handle any type of the video; is it possible to rebuild video from frames and keep same pace of frames?